# How to refine results of a regular expression

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

```
function getPrecedents(thisFormula){

var exp = /(\w+\!)?\$?[A-Z]{1,}(?:\d+)?(\:?\$?\w+)*(?!\()\b/gm;
var results=[];
var result;


while ((result=exp.exec(thisFormula))!== null){
    results.push(result);   
}
 return results;
}
```

From the above code I am getting the following results

```
Trigger_Hires!$AA$15
AD$7
Trigger_Hires!$AC60
Trigger_Hires!$AB60
Rev
Import_Staffing!AD$16
Trigger_Hires!$AC60
Trigger_Hires!$AB60
Customers
Import_Staffing!AD$19
Trigger_Hires!$AC60
```

I would like to eliminate results that are just letters like Rev and Customers either with modified regexp or 2nd loop

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. That worked!!! but I don't understand it. I am new to regular expressions. What I don't understand is why is the index 0    result[0]. Can you please explain.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding a check before adding the match to the `results` array:

```
while (result=exp.exec(thisFormula)) { 
   if (!/^[A-Za-z]+$/.test(result[0])) 
      results.push(result[0]); 
}
```

Note you need to access `result[0]` to get the whole regex match value. To check if the match value is all letters, `^[A-Za-z]+$` regex is used: `^` asserts the position at the start of the string, `[A-Za-z]+` matches 1+ letters and `$` asserts the position at the end of the string.